# How can I run multiple copies of the same test in parallel?

Tags: maven, junit, sbt, parallel-testing

We have a build server that runs any number of builds or test cycles concurrently. Sometimes we get test failures that appear to be caused by different invocations of the same test conflicting with one another.

In a large Scala project with hundreds of tests or more which are written mostly by other people, it would be great if there was a way to directly check each test's level of isolation by running multiple copies of it in parallel (either within a single or across multiple JVMs).

Is there a way to do this directly with sbt or Maven?